# Need to get other value on timer

Tags: android, timer

I have code:

```
TextView txtCurrentTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textClock);
Date dt = new Date();
int hours = dt.getHours();
int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
String curTime = (hours + 4) + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
txtCurrentTime.setText(curTime);
```

on output i get:

> 1:2:1

But i need to get:

> 01:02:01

How i can to get this values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
String curTime = (hours + 4) + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

with :

```
String curTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", (hours + 4), minutes, seconds);
```

More informations about it : [public static String format (String format, Object... args)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)